# Error: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going through Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial near the end, but stuck on the test in Listing 12.29. The two errors that I am getting are:

```
test_should_redirect_following_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1432024588.37s) ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

test_should_redirect_followers_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1432024588.39s)ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

users_controller_test.rb

```
 test "should redirect following when not logged in" do
    get :following, id: @user
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect followers when not logged in" do
    get :followers, id: @user
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
# Returns true if the given user is the current user.   
  def current_user?(user)   
    user == current_user    
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if I need to post some more code, as I am a newcomer to Rails.

update #2, users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                        :following, :followers]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
  end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end
end
```

Comment: That means that your user at the point in your code is nil, do some put statements or a binding.pry around the error and check that the user is being set

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening in your view code -- somewhere you are calling something like `@user.admin?` or `current_user.admin?`. Judging by your test titles, you're checking that the user is redirected if they aren't logged in (i.e., if `@user`/`current_user` is `nil`).

Check your view code for a call of `.admin?` -- that is breaking when you don't have a user.

There are a couple fixes, one of them would be to make the `.admin?` call a try, like:

```
current_user.try(:admin?)
```

`:try` will call the given method (`:admin?`) on `current_user`, but silently return `nil` if `current_user` does not have an `admin?` method (which in this case it doesn't, since `current_user` is `nil`).

Comment: I replaced my instances of `.admin?` with the suggested `current_user.try(:admin?)`, the errors are gone, but I am getting 2 failures: `Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>`, any ideas?

Comment: It might be this in the users.controller.rb:

    `# Confirms the correct user.`
    `def correct_user`
      `@user = User.find(params[:id])`
      `redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user`
    `end`

    `# Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end`

Comment: Where're `correct_user` and `admin_user` being called?

Comment: They are also mentioned in the `users_controller.rb` at the top as:
    `before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]`
    `before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy`

Comment: Looks like your tests are pointed towards the `show` action? So the `correct_user` call won't happen. Could you put your controller code in the question -- might be easier for me to parse.

Comment: I have added the complete code from `users_controller.rb` to the initial question

Comment: Where is `@user` coming from in your test?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when having the same exact error and going crazy.

My mistake was incredibly simple, I accidentally had an older version of the

```
before_action :logged_in_user,
```

in my UsersController

Looked like this, must have just accidentally added it, and not amount of double-checking and copying and pasting nailed it:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                    :following, :followers]
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Deleted the second so it was only this, and errors were gone:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                    :following, :followers]
```